# Python class inheritance new type classes

Tags: python

Im trying to understand class inheritance in Python and created the below inheritance,

Question: When I inherit the class B and invoke method A, it print "Im method B"..Won't it call methodA of class A?

```
class A(object):
    def methodA(self):
        print 'Im method A'


class B(A):
    def methodA(self):
        print 'Im method B'    

class C(A):
    def methodA(self):
        print 'Im method C'    

class D(B,C):
    def methodA(self):
        print 'Im method D'            
def main():
    x = D()
    x.methodA()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, if you want to call the method you're overriding, you'll have to do it manually with [`super`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super):

```
class B(A):
    def methodA(self):
        super(B, self).methodA()
        print 'Im method B'
```

Answer (score 1):

No. Python methods are implicitly [virtual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function) by default. This means that they will always be overridden by the corresponding subclass methods.